# SQL Combine multiple rows into one with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got multiple rows in my result from my query:

for example, the table "Address":

```
Street | Number | City
----------------------
A1     | A2     | A3
B1     | B2     | B3
```

What I actually want is:

```
Address1_Street | Address1_Number | Address1_City | Address2_Street | Address2_Number | Address2_City
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1              | A2              | A3            | B1              | B2              | B3
```

Anyone who knows how I can achieve this?

I've managed to get to this point now (sorry for using other columns, the one above was an example, but I'll guess you'll get the point):

```
select distinct
    a.ID,
    a.Name, 
    ca1.NameLine1 as Address1_NameLine1, 
    ca2.NameLine1 as Address2_NameLine1
from 
    dbo.Accounts a, 
    dbo.Addresses ca1,
    dbo.Addresses ca2
where 
        (a.ID = ca1.AccountID AND a.ID = ca2.AccountID)
    AND (a.Name = 'TEST')
    AND (ca1.ID <> ca2.ID)
```

But I'm still getting 2 rows... where Address1 switches with Address2. Anyone who knows how to only get one? Thanks!

Comment: is there a key on `Address` which determines which rows should be mashed together, or do you simply want every row in the address table?

Comment: In many RDBMSs there is no way to do this for an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: There are MAX 2 Addresses I return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
select ID,
       max(Name) Name,
       max(case when rn=1 then NameLine1 end) Address1_NameLine1,
       max(case when rn=2 then NameLine1 end) Address1_NameLine2
from
(select a.ID,
        a.Name, 
        ca.NameLine1,
        rank() over (partition by a.ID order by ca.ID) rn
 from dbo.Accounts a 
 join dbo.Addresses ca on a.ID = ca.AccountID
 where a.Name = 'TEST') sq
group by ID
```

Comment: One last question... It's possible that the account ONLY has 1 Address, how should I check this? (so Address2_NameLine1 should return NULL)

Comment: @RubenHerman: Actually, the previous version worked OK where there was only one address, but returned two rows where there was a second address - this new version should work OK for either one or two addresses per account.

Comment: Thanks! You were a great help!

Answer (score 1):

```
select address1.* ,address2.* from
Address address1 inner join on Address address2
on address1.userid=address2.userid
```

you can choose inner or left join based on data.

Comment: And this only returns one row then?

Comment: You can choose left join instead of inner join.