# join multiple rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, join

I am not very good in sql but its been days im trying to join multiple rows into columns based on some id.

i have a big table that i insert values from an xml .i am posting part of this xml so any one can test my code.

```
DECLARE @x XML = '
<Events>
<Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5650962" IsOption="1" EventType="0" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="2.2" Home_Points="-0.25" Away_Points="0.25" Away_Odds="1.676" />
    <Total Points="2.25" Over="1.658" Under="2.17" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5650962" IsOption="0" EventType="0" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <MoneyLine Home="2.6" Draw="3.25" Away="2.65" />
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.926" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.962" />
    <Total Points="2.5" Over="1.943" Under="1.901" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5650962" IsOption="1" EventType="0" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.478" Home_Points="0.5" Away_Points="-0.5" Away_Odds="2.58" />
    <Total Points="2.75" Over="2.18" Under="1.654" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5650962" IsOption="1" EventType="0" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.649" Home_Points="0.25" Away_Points="-0.25" Away_Odds="2.24" />
    <Total Points="2" Over="1.431" Under="2.66" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5650962" IsOption="1" EventType="0" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="2.6" Home_Points="-0.5" Away_Points="0.5" Away_Odds="1.472" />
    <Total Points="1.75" Over="1.31" Under="3.09" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="29/10/2013 00:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694776" IsOption="0" EventType="39" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694778" IsOption="1" EventType="200" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694778" IsOption="0" EventType="200" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="2.5" Over="1.952" Under="1.833" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694778" IsOption="1" EventType="200" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="0.5" Over="1.041" Under="9.5" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694778" IsOption="1" EventType="200" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="1.5" Over="1.299" Under="3.45" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694778" IsOption="1" EventType="200" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="3.5" Over="3.45" Under="1.299" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694778" IsOption="1" EventType="200" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="4.5" Over="6.55" Under="1.098" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694778" IsOption="1" EventType="200" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="5.5" Over="12.5" Under="1.017" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694778" IsOption="1" EventType="200" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="6.5" Over="21" Under="1.005" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694779" IsOption="0" EventType="201" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="0.5" Over="1.392" Under="2.8" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694779" IsOption="1" EventType="201" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="1.5" Over="2.9" Under="1.37" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694779" IsOption="1" EventType="201" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="2.5" Over="7" Under="1.07" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694779" IsOption="1" EventType="201" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="3.5" Over="15.75" Under="1.008" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694779" IsOption="1" EventType="201" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694779" IsOption="1" EventType="201" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694779" IsOption="1" EventType="201" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694779" IsOption="1" EventType="201" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694781" IsOption="0" EventType="19" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.87" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.769" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694782" IsOption="0" EventType="20" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <MoneyLine Home="2" Draw="8.25" Away="1.952" />
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.833" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.769" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694784" IsOption="0" EventType="65" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="29.5" Over="1.909" Under="1.741" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694786" IsOption="0" EventType="117" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <MoneyLine Home="2.65" Draw="2.75" Away="2.45" />
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.909" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.769" />
    <Total Points="1.5" Over="1.606" Under="2.1" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694788" IsOption="0" EventType="141" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <MoneyLine Home="3.9" Draw="1.625" Away="3.65" />
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.909" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.8" />
    <Total Points="0.5" Over="1.714" Under="1.952" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694789" IsOption="0" EventType="59" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.909" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.909" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5713513" IsOption="0" EventType="13" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.769" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.952" />
    <Total Points="11.5" Over="2" Under="1.769" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5713514" IsOption="0" EventType="14" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.8" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.909" />
    <Total Points="5.5" Over="2" Under="1.741" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5719201" IsOption="0" EventType="10" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="6.5" Over="1.952" Under="1.69" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5719468" IsOption="0" EventType="11" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="0.5" Over="2.8" Under="1.351" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5654648" IsOption="0" EventType="1" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <MoneyLine Home="3.3" Draw="2" Away="3.3" />
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.917" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.893" />
    <Total Points="1" Over="1.971" Under="1.8" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5654648" IsOption="1" EventType="1" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.478" Home_Points="0.25" Away_Points="-0.25" Away_Odds="2.44" />
    <Total Points="0.75" Over="1.505" Under="2.37" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" ID="5694780" IsOption="0" EventType="2" MEID="2657152">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Getafe" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Athletic Bilbao" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <MoneyLine Home="3" Draw="2.3" Away="2.8" />
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.87" Home_Points="0" Away_Points="0" Away_Odds="1.87" />
    <Total Points="1.25" Over="1.8" Under="1.909" />
  </Event>
<Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" QAID="4423982" EventType="38" EventName="Getafe vs Athletic Bilbao">
    <Participants>
      <Participant Name="Odd">
        <Odds TypeName="Odd/Even" OddsValue="1.952" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="Even">
        <Odds TypeName="Odd/Even" OddsValue="1.833" />
      </Participant>
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" QAID="4423983" EventType="60" EventName="Getafe vs Athletic Bilbao">
    <Participants>
      <Participant Name="0:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="8.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:1">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="6.85" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:2">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="10.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:3">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="18.5" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:4">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="31" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:5">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:6">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:7">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="7" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1:1">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="6.35" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1:2">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="8.75" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1:3">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="17.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1:4">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="31" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1:5">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="67" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1:6">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="11.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2:1">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="9.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2:2">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="13" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2:3">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="23" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2:4">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="41" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2:5">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="3:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="21.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="3:1">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="19" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="3:2">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="24.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="3:3">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="31" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="3:4">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="67" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="4:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="41" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="4:1">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="31" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="4:2">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="41" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="4:3">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="67" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="4:4">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="5:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="5:1">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="5:2">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="6:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="6:1">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="7:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" QAID="4423985" EventType="61" EventName="Getafe vs Athletic Bilbao">
    <Participants>
      <Participant Name="1 or X">
        <Odds TypeName="Double Chance" OddsValue="1.4" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="X or 2">
        <Odds TypeName="Double Chance" OddsValue="1.357" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1 or 2">
        <Odds TypeName="Double Chance" OddsValue="1.308" />
      </Participant>
    </Participants>
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="28/10/2013 20:00:00" Branch="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="Spain - La Liga" LeagueID="10146" QAID="4423986" EventType="62" EventName="Getafe vs Athletic Bilbao">
    <Participants>
      <Participant Name="1/1">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="4.45" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1/2">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="27.5" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="1/X">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="14" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2/X">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="14" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="X/X">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="4.9" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2/1">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="2/2">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="4.1" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="X/1">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="6.4" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="X/2">
        <Odds TypeName="Halftime/Fulltime" OddsValue="6" />
      </Participant>
    </Participants>
  </Event>
</Events>
```

'

i read this xml with this query

```
select
    T.C.value('@DateTimeGMT', 'varchar(100)') as DateTimeGMT,
    T.C.value('@Branch', 'varchar(100)') as Branch,
    T.C.value('@BranchID', 'int') as BranchID,
    T.C.value('@League', 'varchar(100)') as League,
    T.C.value('@LeagueID', 'int') as LeagueID,
    T.C.value('@IsOption', 'int') as IsOption,
    T.C.value('@EventType', 'int') as EventType,
    T.C.value('@MEID', 'int') as MEID,
    T.C.value('@QAID', 'int') as QAID,
    T.C.value('@EventName', 'varchar(500)') as EventName,
    T.C.value('(Participants/Participant1)[1]/@Name', 'varchar(100)') as Home,
    T.C.value('(Participants/Participant2)[1]/@Name', 'varchar(100)') as Away,
    T.C.value('(MoneyLine)[1]/@Home', 'varchar(5)') as [1],
    T.C.value('(MoneyLine)[1]/@Draw', 'varchar(5)') as [X],
    T.C.value('(MoneyLine)[1]/@Away', 'varchar(5)') as [2],
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Home_Points', 'float') as Spread_Home_Points,
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Home_Odds', 'float') as Spread_Home_Odds,
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Away_Points', 'float') as Spread_Away_Points,
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Away_Odds', 'float') as Spread_Away_Odds,
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Away_Odds', 'float') as Spread_Away_Odds,
    T.C.value('(Total)[1]/@Points', 'float') as Total_Points,
    T.C.value('(Total)[1]/@Over', 'float') as Lart,
    T.C.value('(Total)[1]/@Under', 'float') as Posht,
    P.C.value('@Name', 'varchar(100)') as Rubrika,
    P.C.value('(Odds)[1]/@OddsValue', 'varchar(100)') as Koefic
from @x.nodes('Events/Event') as T(C)
    outer apply T.C.nodes('Participants/Participant') as P(C)
```

and i put this result table into an existing table. my xml is really big and usually has 20000 rows

I want a query that join rows based on condition into columns
There is  the first unique id which is MEID and the second one is EventName which is equal  `Home  + ' vs ' + Away`
the result query should look like this

`DateGMT, MEID,Branch,Home,Away,[1],[X],[2], other columns*` 
other columns* are columns generated from table where `Eventname = Home  + ' vs ' + Away`
for example all values  from this xml part

```
<Participant Name="0:0">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="8.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:1">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="6.85" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:2">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="10.25" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:3">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="18.5" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:4">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="31" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:5">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:6">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
      <Participant Name="0:7">
        <Odds TypeName="Exact Score" OddsValue="101" />
      </Participant>
```

where Participant Name="0:6" and OddsValue="8.25" is its value

so my result would be

```
`DateGMT,        MEID,      Branch,    Home,   Away,            [1],    [X],    [2], "0:0"  ,"0:1"  ,"0:2"  ,"0:3" ...
28/10/2013 2*,   2657152,   Soccer,    Getafe, Athletic Bilbao, 2.6,    3.25,   2.65, 8.25  ,   6.85,   10.25,   18.5 ...`
```

is there a way how to do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: if you have fixed number of columns, it's relatively easy to do. It also possible to do with dynamic SQL for any number of columns, but it's usually not very good idea to do this in SQL

Comment: @RomanPekar Actually there is a fixed number of columns,but its a large number. i want to do it dynamically only for rows where EventName is in consideration as second xml ive posted.

Comment: I can do this from VB,but i am strugling doing it in sql.

Comment: I found another question on here that is the same that you are trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290114/sql-combine-multiple-rows-into-one-with-multiple-columns